# PeerJs user-defined id unable to relay stream

Tags: node.js, webrtc, peerjs

I am attempting to set up a live streaming feature between two users using PeerJS. I am using Next.js for the frontend and Socket.IO along with Node.js for the backend. The functionality works properly when I establish the connection using a randomly generated peer ID. However, when I try to define my own custom ID, PeerJS fails to relay the stream. I have provided the code below for your reference. Please take a look:

**Broadcaster** (this person will relay his video stream to proctor

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Video from '../../components/video';
// import { AuthContext } from "@/context/auth.context";

const Broadcaster = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const peerInstance = useRef(null);
  const socketRef = useRef(null);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const [videoOn, setVideoOn] = useState(true);
  const brod_id = '35364a7c-1894-4ed6-abe8-f66835f021c4';

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('http://localhost:3010');

    import('peerjs').then(({ default: Peer }) => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: { width: 550, height: 350 }, audio: false })
        .then((stream) => {
          videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
          console.log(`id ${id}`);
          peerInstance.current = new Peer(brod_id);

          peerInstance.current.on('open', (id) => {
            console.log('candidate id c', id);
            console.log(`Broadcast username change`);
            socketRef.current.emit('username-change', {
              username: id,
            });
            socketRef.current.emit('peer-id', id);
            socketRef.current.on('admin-joined', async (adminId) => {
              console.log(`Broadcaset username-change && Admin Joined`);
              socketRef.current.emit('username-change', {
                username: id,
              });
              console.log('calling .....');
              console.log('PROCTOR ID', adminId);
              const call = await peerInstance.current.call(adminId, stream);
            });
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Broadcaster( useEffect ): ${error}`);
        });
    });
  }, [videoOn]);

  return <Video video={videoRef} videoOn={videoOn}></Video>;
};

export default Broadcaster;
```

**Proctor** this person will receive the broadcaster's video stream

```
import Viewer from '@/components/viewer';
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import DraggableModal from '@/components/draggable-modal';
import Video from '@/components/video';

function ProctorPage() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [candidates, setCandidates] = useState([]);
  const [activeUsers, setActiveUsers] = useState([]);
  const [showVideo, setShowVideo] = useState(false);
  const socketRef = useRef(null);
  const proctorPeerInstance = useRef(null);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const fetchCandidates = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3010/user');
      setCandidates(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Viewer( fetchCandidates ) ${error}`);
    }
  };

  const DraggableModalContent = (
    <div>
      {loading && <div>Loading</div>}
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay playsInline />
    </div>
  );

  const proctor_id = '35364a7c-1894-4ed6-abe8-f66835f021c5';

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setShowVideo(true);
    import('peerjs').then(({ default: Peer }) => {
      proctorPeerInstance.current = new Peer(proctor_id);

      proctorPeerInstance.current.on('open', (id) => {
        socketRef.current.emit('admin-id', id);

        proctorPeerInstance.current.on('call', (call) => {

          navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
            .then((stream) => {
              call.answer(stream);
              call.on('stream', (remoteStream) => {
                console.log(
                  'Streaming candidate video',
                  remoteStream,
                  videoRef
                );
                videoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
                setLoading(false);
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error accessing media devices:', error);
            });
        });
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect('http://localhost:3010');
    fetchCandidates();

    socketRef.current.on('ongoing-stream', (username) => {
      console.log('change', username);
      setActiveUsers((prevActiveUsers) => {
        const updatedActiveUsers = [...prevActiveUsers, username];
        return updatedActiveUsers;
      });
    });
    console.log('Active Users: ', activeUsers);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {candidates.map((candidate) => {
          const isActive = activeUsers.includes(candidate.id.toString());
          return (
            <Viewer
              id={candidate.id}
              name={candidate.first_name}
              email={candidate.email}
              onClick={handleClick}
            ></Viewer>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      {showVideo && (
        <DraggableModal
          title="Test title"
          content={DraggableModalContent}
          open={showVideo}
          setOpen={setShowVideo}
        ></DraggableModal>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default ProctorPage;
```

***Nodejs + Socket.io + Prisma Backend***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const cors = require("cors");
const { readSync } = require("fs");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    // url for frontend
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  },
});

adminAddress = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // console.log( `User Connected: ${ socket.id }` );
  socket.on("send-message", (data) => {
    console.log("DATA: ", data);
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive-message", data);
  });

  socket.on("peer-id", (userId) => {
    console.log("Peer Id Received: ", userId);
    socket.broadcast.emit("candidate-joined", userId);
  });

  socket.on("admin-id", (adminId) => {
    console.log("Admin ID received: ", adminId);
    socket.broadcast.emit("admin-joined", adminId);
  });

  socket.on("username-change", (data) => {
    console.log(`username Change: ${data.username}`);
    socket.broadcast.emit("ongoing-stream", data.username);
  });
});

app.get("/user", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
  res.json(users);
});

app.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const result = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name,
      email,
      password,
    },
  });
  res.json({
    message: "User created successfully",
  });
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", req.body);
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: email,
    },
  });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: " User not found" });
  }

  const passwordMatch = user.password == password;
  if (!passwordMatch) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: "Password is incorrect" });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Login successful", id: user.id });
});

server.listen(3010, () => {
  console.log("Server is running");
});
```

I've trying to solve this issue since past few hours, without any success. Any help is appreciated